# How do I make a Install.sh of Nebeans Development version

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I have obtained the sources for Netbeans and built using Ant, thus:-

```
$mkdir -p /home/<user>/projects/netbeans-main
$cd /home/<user>/projects/netbeans-main
$hg clone http://hg.netbeans.org/main
$cd /home/<user>/projects/netbeans-main/main
$export ANT_OPTS="-Xmx2G"
$ant
```

This works, and I can run Netbeans in the source tree, thus:-

```
$ant tryme   <- uses a temp enviroment
$./nbbuild/netbeans/bin/netbeans  <- uses my current user environment
```

But I cannot find any info on how to make a "netbeans-8.2-linux.sh", like I downloaded.
I want to install this development version on another linux box.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that $ant just builds No-ZIP
To build a complete netbeans IDE, one needs to use

```
$ant build
```

After the build, the following has been created

```
./nbbuild/NetBeans-dev-20180301-aca67cbee053-full.zip
```

All the build options can be found from

```
$ant -p
```

I'd seen a reference to this in something I googled, but not cognized that it started with a capital N.

Still don't know how "netbeans-8.2-linux.sh" is created, but I guess the Zip is sufficient.